# How to fix imshow() showing grey image

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to show the webcam capture on screen in my raspberry pi. It shows first frame with no problem but next ones are displayed as grey frames.

This works on windows but not on raspberry.

```
import cv2 as cv

cap = cv.VideoCapture(0)
ret, frame = cap.read()
cv.imshow('frame0',frame)
while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv.imshow('frame',frame)
    if cv.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

First install the `Picamera` module and then try:

```
# import the necessary packages
from picamera.array import PiRGBArray
from picamera import PiCamera
import time
import cv2

# initialize the camera and grab a reference to the raw camera capture
camera = PiCamera()
camera.resolution = (640, 480)
camera.framerate = 32
rawCapture = PiRGBArray(camera, size=(640, 480))

# allow the camera to warmup
time.sleep(0.1)

# capture frames from the camera
for frame in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture, format="bgr", use_video_port=True):
    # grab the raw NumPy array representing the image, then initialize the timestamp
    # and occupied/unoccupied text
    image = frame.array

    # show the frame
    cv2.imshow("Frame", image)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

    # clear the stream in preparation for the next frame
    rawCapture.truncate(0)

    # if the `q` key was pressed, break from the loop
    if key == ord("q"):
        break
```

Source: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/03/30/accessing-the-raspberry-pi-camera-with-opencv-and-python/

Comment: Doesn´t work. Looks like first frame of the video stream is shown with no problem (last for a very short time in screen) but next ones are still gray.

Comment: Try following the complete tutorial in the link

Comment: Doesn't work. Step 6 of that tutorial shows the image gray when showing the video stream. The previous step showing a photo instead of a video works though.

Comment: that's weird, check that you have all the modules up to date.